# Term for same root word but words with different meaning

Tags: etymology, terminology, doublets

Some words have the same etymology, root, but mean different things, such as mysterious and mystical.  What are some other pairs (or more) that fall into this category, and what exactly is this category called?

Comment: There are lots of possible answers to that (words sharing the same root but whose meaning have diverged), so this should be CW, shouldn't it?

Comment: My favorite example is awful and awesome. At some point, awful did also have the same connotation as awesome, but in modern usage, they are almost antonyms.

Comment: Sanguine and Sanguinary. "Happy" and "bloodthirsty" respectively. Both have roots in L. sanguineus "of blood". (Think rosy cheeks)

Answer (score 6):

There are actually lots of these. They are called [doublets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet_%28linguistics%29).

My favorite example, which is not mentioned on that Wikipedia page, is the following:

*Genre*, *gender*, *generic*, and *genus* all come from the Latin *genus* meaning "kind/class" (although the word actually goes all the way back to Proto-Indo-European *gen-/*gon-/*gn- meaning "produce, beget, be born").

Comment: Does that list also include 'genetic', 'generate', 'genealogy', and 'genesis'?

Comment: Thank you. That is the precise information I was looking for.  Thank all three of you who responded.  I'm much obliged.

Comment: @oosterwal: Yes, and probably several others!

Comment: and 'degenerate', 'genitalia', 'gentleman', and 'genuine'.

Comment: If we include other non-Latin/non-Greek cognates of this PIE root (which, incidentally, is _*ĝenh₁-_, not just _*gen-_), it also includes words like _kind_, _kin_, _kind(ergarten)_, _king_, _genius_, _germ_, _german_, _germane_, _gentle_, _gentile_, _gentility_, _progenitor_, _engine_, _ingenious_, _gin (trap)_, etc. It’s a **very** productive (!) root that has begotten (!) a vast variety of words and meanings in various languages.

Answer (score 3):

The word to describe this situation (about words) is **cognate**. 'Skirt' and 'shirt' are cognate because they have a word in common etymologically.

Comment: That pair is also a doublet because they're both English...

Answer (score 3):

Just to point out, doublets are cognates within a single language.

My favorite pair is galaxy and lactose, which come from the Greek word for milk, gala. The genitive is galaktos. Apparently, Milky Way wasn't a weird choice of name at all...

Comment: Lactose is from Latin (ultimately lac, lactis = milk), whereas galaxy (and galactose) are from Greek. Probably both from proto IE root glakt-

Answer (score 2):

My favourite pair is "canon" (=rule) and "cannon" (=weapon). Both from the same Greek word (kanna) meaning a reed, probably from a semitic root. I think that is an awesome stretch of meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Cognates with different meanings from different languages/dialects are known as [False Friends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friends).